# Change Default Scale Method Setting for KDE Wallpapers

Tags: kubuntu, kde, desktop-background, default, system-settings

I wish to change the **default** scaling method for the desktop wallpaper in KDE(more specifically Kubuntu) by *editing the configuration file* KDE uses to fill in those defaults on a fresh install.  So that, when any new account is created, or someone is installing the OS, it is set to Scaled & Cropped instead of zoomed or scaled.

I know that gnome has this default setting stored in,

```
/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/ubuntu-wallpapers.xml
```

or in,

```
/usr/share/gconf/schemas/desktop_gnome_background.schemas
```

I have been searching the linux filesystem for a couple days know to find the KDE equivalent of the files listed above, but with no luck.

I have thoroughly search '*/usr/share/kununtu-default-settings*' but there doesn't seem to be any configuration file for the wallpaper settings listed there.  At this point I am assuming another program, not built into KDE, is handling the wallpaper, I don't know how to determine this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**KDE Plasma desktop**

The KDE configuration files: http://techbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/Configuration_Files

The KDE is using the plasma desktop and the wallpaper is an applet/widget. The plasma desktop applet configuration file is: plasma-desktop-appletsrc.

The wallpaper setting can be set for the each activity/desktop.

The positioning information is saved to the 'wallpaperposition=X'

wallpaperposition=0 is 'Scaled'

wallpaperposition=1 is 'Centered'

wallpaperposition=2 is 'Scaled & Cropped'

wallpaperposition=3 is 'Tiled'

wallpaperposition=4 is 'Center Tiled'

wallpaperposition=5 is 'Scaled, keep proportions'

**kde4rc**

The default configuration profile path is read from the /etc/kde4rc. The information is used when the new user default configuration files are made.

The Kubuntu is using:

```
[Directories-default]
prefixes=/usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kde4-profile/default/
```

the user can change this - as example at here

```
[Directories-default]
prefixes=/usr/share/my-default-settings/kde4-profile/default/
```

The Kubuntu has in the /usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kde4-profile/default/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc:

```
[AppletGlobals][plasma_applet_launcher]
SwitchTabsOnHover=false
askBeforeRemoval=true
```

You could edit your plasma desktop and then copy your ~/.kde/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc to the /usr/share/my-default-settings/kde4-profile/default/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc. The new user will then has your plasma applet settings as start default.