# How to save customized Kde desktop for all desktop

Tags: kubuntu, kde4

Guys I love to customize my Kubuntu Desktop and on my home computer I did something with Homerun and a custom Desktop Theme but whenever I create a new User account that simple KDE desktop comes back so how can I apply my customizations to all accounts without starting from scratch on every account.

Answer (score 1):

**Kubuntu defaults / kde4rc**

The default configuration profile path is read from the /etc/kde4rc. The information is used when the new user default configuration files are made.

The Kubuntu is using:

```
[Directories-default]
 prefixes=/usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kde4-profile/default/
```

The /usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kde4-profile/default/share/config/default_configuration_filerc is installed to the ~/.kde/share/config/default_configuration_filerc when the KDE is started at the first time - When there is no existing ~/.kde/share/config/default_configuration_filerc file.

You could edit your desktop and then copy your ~/.kde/share/config/configuration_filerc to the /usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kde4-profile/default/share/config/default_configuration_filerc. The new user will then has your settings as start default.

**Examples**

- [Change Default Scale Method Setting for KDE Wallpapers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434004/change-default-scale-method-setting-for-kde-wallpapers)
- https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?63304-Kubuntu-s-default-font&p=349797&viewfull=1#post349797